# How to select large amount of data in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table mysql with 70 million records. I want to search something on this but my method spent too much time . I want to reduce it. how to reduce the time select (search a record)?

My table structure:

```
Member
ID || Username || Fullname
70 million records
```

My sql query :

```
     "Select Fullname from Member where ID=id"
```

Comment: I suppose ID is indexed?

Comment: Can you `describe member` and post it here?

Comment: @Terry if it took too much time, I suppose not :P  How to fix: Index it; throw more hardware at it, [partition](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html) the table FROM Docs: "Some queries can be greatly optimized in virtue of the fact that data satisfying a given WHERE clause can be stored only on one or more partitions, which automatically excludes any remaining partitions from the search."